# Is there a definitive reference book/website for the general aspects of the commercial flight industry?

Tags: recommendations

I come from the aviation stack exchange, since they considered this stack would be better suited to answer my question.

I am a programmer that recently started working for a project related to commercial airlines. I haven't worked for this industry before, so there's a lot of concepts I still need to learn. My question is regarding a well known/official reference book/website that can explain the industry to me (for example, I recently learned about the IATA, the Amadeus and SalesForce systems, what information flight numbers are comprised of, what happens when a flight is overbooked, the marketing airline vs the operating one on a given flight, among others).

The IATA website has some articles already, but I'm interested on a general reference book where I can look up the concepts that come up on my day to day.

Comment: The legal framework is described in the Chicago Convention (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_on_International_Civil_Aviation) but I guess you're asking about the operational rules?

Comment: You might like to read [Airlines 101 - A Primer For Dummies](http://libraryonline.erau.edu/online-full-text/books-online/Airlines101.pdf)
(no offence meant). It's a general read about the background and history of the aviation industry: "*The piece was written as an introduction to the industry for an audience presumed to have no knowledge of the airline business.*"

Comment: @DaveGremlin thanks for this, but yes, I mean operational more than anything.

Comment: @WeatherVane this is wonderful, thank you!